# Difference between two (2) dates/times. Returns negative values

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get the minute difference between two dates/times

my query is

> Select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2017-06-06 16:01:59','2017-06-06 15:49:25') as
>   minutes_difference into table1

'show my table1 rows

> Select * from  table1

But I am getting a negative value

```
minute_difference = -12
```

here is my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9BVh.png)

Please tell me what's wrong with my query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the last two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2017-06-06 15:49:25','2017-06-06 16:01:59') as minutes_difference into table1
```

Like this, Lower date should be in the first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using function ABS?

Select ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2017-06-06 16:01:59','2017-06-06 15:49:25')) as minutes_difference into table1